# Image drawn into canvas shape

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I created a shape in canvas and want to drawn an image in it.

So far I can clip the image to the shape but I want the image to adapt it self with the Free Transform -> Distort effect or something similar.

In the example:

- The image on the left is the clipped one.
- The image on the right is the original.
- The bottom image is the result I want to achieve.

The code can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/NAe9c/

The code result can be seen here: http://www.tribalddb.pt/final.jpg

**edited:** 
Thank You all
I accepted that answer to this issue but I found another alternative to my problem, CSS 3D.
I didn't know it until now =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can draw things flat and have them rendered in perspective. You can't do it simply with a 2D transform so there's a bit of math to the ordeal if you want to use the 2D context but nothing insane.

I'd suggest doing a search for "canvas perspective transform" and you'll find a lot of demos, like this one:

http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/canvas/perspective.html

Comment: haha nice, I was just looking at your other answer that suggested this. I also found this which is pretty easy to understand as well http://jsdo.it/hakim/simple_perspective

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do perspective correction for something like this, I think it would be easier to get a library to do it for you, have considered using:

[Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/)

Comment: Thanks, but I think that using a 3D environment just to achieve this is a bit overwhelming =P

Comment: Possibly, but the maths involved in doing this can also be overwhelming, its fairly easy using Three.js